# combination with array of a length set

Tags: javascript

I have one array named 's' now I need to print from this array all
combination/option of 'len' now I hvae this code but I cant print all
option and I don't know what its wrong finally I need will print like ABC , BCD , CDE , ABD , , BDE etc.....

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="result"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
    var len = 2
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length - len + 1; i++) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML + s.slice(i, i + len) + "<br/>";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output ?

Comment: ABC,
BCD,
CDE  you mind so oder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate a tree of all elements, where you go into one direction with the element and in the other without the actual element. Proceed until the temporary array has the wanted lenght or if you reached the last element of the array.

Return only three elements.

Basically you need for a recursive function an check for leaving the function.

In this case there are two

- if length of temp array matches the wanted length, then add temp to result;
- if index is equal to length of the array with the item;

then exit the function and stop recursion.

The main part is to start a new recursion, one with the element at index and one without.

```js
function getCombinations(array, length) {

    function fork(i, t) {                   // recursive fn with index & temp array
        if (t.length === length) {          // check temp length
            result.push(t);                 // push collected values
            return;                         // exit function
        }
        if (i === array.length) {           // check if index is out of range
            return;                         // exit function
        }
        fork(i + 1, t.concat([array[i]]));  // call for with a new letter from index
        fork(i + 1, t);                     // call for without a new letter
    }

    var result = [];                        // for keeping the part results
    fork(0, []);                            // start with index zero and empty temp array
    return result;                          // return result
}

var names = ['anne', 'bert', 'cara', 'dirk', 'eva'],
    result = getCombinations(names, 3);

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: hey bro its work fantastic hier with a "Run code snippet" but in my goggle chrome i cant see this of the console F12 why?

Comment: You can give some explanations in the wave line code what exactly happens

Comment: i need but last line (getCombinations('ABCDE'.split(''), 3), 0, 4);                     Actually using once array and not "ABCDE"

Comment: the split returns an array with single letters. just lazy writing.

Comment: nina danke viel mal

Comment: kann ich dir noch ein fragen oder muss ich noch ein post schriben weil ich habe one code funkzioniert gyt und ich brauche einfach dein code past bei meine code aber ich muss deine code past eine array mit a viel name von leute like nina shabi ella und so aber in dein code wenn ich dich richtig verschtande kann ich nur mit chars ohne string glich namen das richtig ? und noch mal erlich danke viel viel mal nina

Comment: ok ich habe ein array var cars = ["levi", "shabi", "nina" , "Scholz"];  wie ich kann diese array geben in deine code by leste line  aber ich will nicht schreiben ale namen ich habe schom ein array bekommen ale info from infut user oder by click on items und nacher wo ich hbe schon diese array ich brauche deine code aber nur mit var von array nicht ale namen noch mal schreiben verschtanden mir nina und danke viel mal

Comment: you could use the variable `names` with the items, you need. the result is an array (please have a look here: [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array))

Comment: hey mamamia du bist eine psico coder lek mir ...... du bist am besten bitte kannst dumir schikhe ein frune requst in facebook hhh bitte du bist so gut und ich frund mich wenn ich kannen eine person wie du ich laben in schweiz und du wo labst du deutchland?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139017/discussion-between-shabi-levi-and-nina-scholz).

Comment: In any case the code actually works pretty well
I have a table with 3 options
  1 X 2
And each choice that the code is clicked will take a selection and the sum
Now your code actually gives the player an option to make a systematic form
5/6 4/6 3/6 2/6 ETC ...
But in my code, every ARRAY has its own, for example, with a click on 1
There are 3 actions in the code
1. ARRAY SUM
2 ARRAY VALUE
3.ARRAY GAMES I
  As in the following example:

Games = ['Andorra - Faroe Islands', 'Bosnia - Gibraltar','Cyprus -Estonia','Sweden - Belarus'];

Comment: var games = ['Andorra - Faroe Islands',
             'Bosnia  - Gibraltar',
             'Cyprus - Estonia',
             'Sweden - Belarus'],
result = getCombinations(games, 3);

var choice = ['Andorra',
             'Gibraltar',
             'Cyprus',
             'draw'],
result2 = getCombinations(choice, 3);

var value = ['3.6',
             '2.4',
             '2.3',
             '4.5'],
result3 = getCombinations(value, 3);

Comment: i need push another array with all the first value from all array like            array 1 = a b c    array 2 = 1 2 3     array = x y z       allTogether = a1x,b2y,c3z and printed

Comment: @ShabiLevi, it is not solvable in the comments.

Comment: Hi how are you..
I really need your help ...
Can you write me the same code in PHP? please

Comment: @ShabiLevi, sorry, actually i can't.

Comment: I began to ask that no one answered her.
I said who could answer it because you recorded me the code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function combinationArr(chars) {
  var resultArr = [];
  var func = function(prefix, chars) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
      resultArr.push(prefix + chars[i]);
      func(prefix + chars[i], chars.slice(i + 1));
    }
  }
  func('', chars);
  return resultArr;
}

var combinations = combinationArr(["A", "B", "C","D","E"]);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = combinations;
```

html

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: its not good for me i nees just ABC,BCD not all a chars like your code tahnk you